# Trigger buttons based on values socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, real-time

How can i change this to get worked by using value not ID. The function should search for the button with the exact value and run the click function.I tried in several ways but was not successful. so can anyone please help me get through this. I want ti make buttons with same values get clicked

app.js

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a client has connected');
    socket.on('clicked', function() {
        io.emit('clicked');
    });
    socket.on('clicked1', function() {
        io.emit('clicked1');
    });

});



console.log('socket.io server started at port 3000');
```

button.html

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Testing socket.io</title>
      <style>.tictac{
    width:100px;height:100px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    background:#16ed07; 
    color: #000000; 
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9; 
    font-size: 150%;
    }
    </style>
      </head>
    <body>
    <form>
      <button type="button" id="sq1" NAME="sqrone" class="tictac"  onClick="onClickHandler(this)"><span id="1" ></span></button>

      <button type="button" id="sq2" NAME="sqrtwo" class="tictac"  onClick="onClickHandler(this)">
      <span id="2" ></span></button>



      </form>


      <h2 id="alert"> waiting...</h2>
      <script language="JavaScript">

    function addComment()
    {
        var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

        var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
        l = unescape(temp[1]);

        temp = parameters[1].split("=");
        c = unescape(temp[1]);

        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = l;
        document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = c;
    }
addComment();

</script>



      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>

      <script>
        var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
        socket.on('connect', function() {
          document.getElementById("sq1").addEventListener("click", function (data) {
        socket.emit("clicked");

          });

           document.getElementById("sq2").addEventListener("click", function (data) {


              socket.emit("clicked1");

          });

         });
        socket.on('clicked', function(data) {

        //if condition
          console.log('clicked');
          document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "1 clicked";

          onClickHandler(sq1);

        });
       socket.on('clicked1', function() {

        //if condition
          console.log('clicked1');
          document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "2 clicked";

          onClickHandler(sq2);

        });




      </script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
function onClickHandler(elem) {
elem.style.background = 'red';
elem.style.color = 'black';
}
</script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">




<!--webfonts-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--//webfonts-->

</head>
<body bgcolor="#3C4C55">
<style>.tictac{
width:50px;height:30px;padding: 5px;  font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #D9D9D9; font-size: 75%;
</style>

<center>
</br></br></br></br></br></br>
<form method="get" action="button.html">
<table border="15" cellpadding="5" align="center" style="background-color:orange" >
    <tr>

<td>
<input type="number" id="sq1" name="sqrone" value=""  placeholder="Value" class="tictac"  />
<input type="number" id="sq2" name="sqrtwo" value=""  placeholder="Value" class="tictac"  />
</td>

</tr>

</table>
</br></br>

<div>
                <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="saveVal()">

    </div>



</form>
        </center>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is what i have tried so far**

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");

var click = document.getElementById("sq1");
var clicka = document.getElementById("sq2");

var required = document.getElementById("sq1").value;
var requireda = document.getElementById("sq2").value;

socket.on('connect', function() {

  click.addEventListener("click", function () {

socket.emit("clicked");

  });

  }

  clicka.addEventListener("click", function () {

    socket.emit("clicked1");

  });


 });
 if (required===l || requireda===c) {
socket.on('clicked', function() {


  console.log('clicked');
  document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "1 clicked";

  onClickHandler(sq1);

});
}
else if(required===c || requireda===l) {
```

socket.on('clicked1', function() {

```
//if condition
  console.log('clicked1');
  document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "2 clicked";

  onClickHandler(sq2);

});
}
```

Comment: Can you update your code so that it's valid for testing? also if you can include your front and backend code separately

Comment: @lix i have updates as you asked.

Comment: i want ti make buttons with same values get clicked